# Calculate the SD in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation of some points in matlab using the std2 build-in function. I have a table (20*2) with values. I am using the function

```
x = std2(table1(1:20, 2));
```

but I get only the SD of the second column. 
How can I get from row 1 the columns 1 and 2 to calculate for all the points the SD? Basically, how can I have access to a specific row and column in a table?

Does anyone know how can I do it?

Comment: you are indexing the second column in table1(1:20,2), std2 does whole matrices/Arrays, simply std2(table1) should do the trick. To access specific rows, index them - table1(1,:) is the first row etc. ALSO if you are using matrices, it is slightly faster using std, since std2 does std(A(:))

Comment: and the results should be a list of values of just one value?

Comment: depends on how you are using it, if you want the std of each column, you could just do std(table1) which should give you the stud of each column.

Comment: @usr9 do you want to compute the standard deviation for the data in the whole table or for the data in each column separately?

Comment: i want to compute the SD for the data in each row

Comment: then you could do std(table1') where the ` flips the matrix around.

Comment: thats perfect, it is what i want. But this return a table 1*20 how can i get 20*1 table?

Comment: you flip it again, std(table1')'

Comment: So having read these comments, I'm very confused about what you are hoping to achieve. Why on earth would you compute standard deviations using *two* samples?

Comment: @mikkola lol, I was wondering the same. This is also a duplicated question

Comment: I have to read an image, and extract the the features and select that features where have SD grater than the 25. this way is not right?

Comment: well, it looks like you are doing some edge detection. I don't think it is wrong, but I cannot be sure with the given information.

Comment: @usr9 Standard deviation quantifies the amount of variation in a collection of data values. It is nonsensical to compute standard deviation when the aforementioned collection consists of *two* data values.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your help, I will look more about this because you are right in this point. :)